# JQuery UI Datepicker - Get the range from the start to end date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

May I know how can I use JQuery UI Datepicker to get the range of the date **between** StartDate and EndDate?

Example:

Start date: 06-March-2014
End date:   09-March-2014

So, my table should able to display output like below.

1. 06-March-2014
2. 07-March-2014
3. 08-March-2014
4. 09-March-2014

Is that possible to do it?
Or I should use method like this

```
var totalDay = endDate - startDate;

for(var i = 0; i < totalDay; i++) {
    /* Display table output */
}
```

If I want to use the method like this, how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: See the answer :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: If u using the datepicker u can set mindate and max date then calender will show only that date range.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I cannot saw this question. :(

Comment: @Neha, I need to get the range of the date in order to display the column. :(

Comment: Are u looking something like this solution.. - http://jsfiddle.net/7DHVr/11/

Comment: @Neha, Nope. It is something to let users choose start date and end date. And the system will display the table column based on the range of the date.

You get what I mean? >_< Sorry my English quite weak.

Comment: ok! so user will choose dates from datepicker (so u have 2 date picker? start and end) and u will  display the range on some div like above date text...??

Comment: @Neha, yeah, you are absolutely right. XD
Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Sorry took me bit time(was busy) here is the thing u looking - http://jsfiddle.net/7DHVr/15/

Comment: @Blackie did u look the fiddle, does it help?

Comment: @Neha, Yes, I saw it. But it is not I want.